# iText alignment of Acrofield [C#]

Tags: c#, itext, text-alignment, acrofields

I got a PDF file with some Acrofields. 
I'd like the text of one textfield to be centered.

I tried:

```
var centeredField = stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldItem(fieldname);
centeredField.GetMerged(0).Put(PdfName.Q, new PdfNumber(PdfFormField.Q_CENTER));
```

Which works for text that is set in the code afterwards (with SetField).
But as soon as I open the PDF and edit the text of the field, it get's aligned left again...

Any ideas where my code's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading and playing around I finally managed to get a working solution:

```
var centeredField = stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldItem(fieldname);
centeredField.GetWidget(0).Put(PdfName.Q, new PdfNumber(PdfFormField.Q_CENTER));
```

The difference is the "GetWidget" instead of GetMerged.